# Collect facebook live stream public data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any API  for collecting facebook public data as live feed .I read about about public feed API  for collecting data but I can't apply for that right now and also Its not free,Also the Open stream API  but its outdated and not supported .Is there any other way to get facebook  public data as live  feed ?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no such way.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible if I use NodeJs?

Comment: It's not about a certain technology, as @luschn said in his answer. There's just no endpoint to get the data from at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/

> Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time.

Meaning, there is no way to do that, at least not for you. It does not matter if you use PHP, Node.js or any other server language.

Comment: I can't find any information on how to become a facebook media partner (that is to have access to that public feed streaming API). Has any one tried to go down that alley?

Comment: "You cannot apply to use the API at this time" - meaning, there is no information to find. You just can´t become a partner right now.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. Do you know of any of facebook's media partner reselling access to that data via an API?

Comment: no, but i doubt they would do that, and i am pretty sure they are not allowed to.